# Javascript Add/Remove unique cloned div

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dropdown that I want to be cloned and have a unique id. I managed to do it and it works on my website.

I am trying to make a "x" button to removed added clones and I can't get it to work.

**The javascript:**

```
var counter = 1;
function addInput(divName, template){
    if (counter == 5)  {
        document.getElementById("add_more_text").remove();
    } else {
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newdiv.innerHTML = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
        document.getElementById(template).appendChild(newdiv);
        counter++;
    }

    var selectElements = document.querySelectorAll('select');
    for (var i = 0; i < selectElements.length; i++){
        selectElements[i].id = 'id-' + i;
        selectElements[i].name = 'category' + i;
    }
}
function removeInput(divName, template){
    document.getElementById(template).removeChild(divName);
    counter--;
}
```

**The html:**

```
<div id="template">
    <select name="category0"><option>hi</option></select> 
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="removeInput('template', 'add_more');">x</a>                                       
</div>
<div id="add_more"></div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="addInput('template', 'add_more');" id="add_more_text">+ Add more</a>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rjXXa/1/)

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Having fixed your jQuery, this is the error it produces `Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node. ` All the clones contain this `<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="removeInput('template', 'add_more');">x</a>` - are you forgetting to modify the innerHTML?

Comment: Yeah I am not sure how to do that. i though copying the else statement and itstead of append put remove but that didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpler to modify remove function as follows:

```
function removeInput(obj) {
    if (obj.parentNode.className == 'added') {
        obj.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(obj.parentNode);
        counter--;
    }
}
```

And have a link in template like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="removeInput(this);">x</a>
```

Class `added` is to distinguish new clones that can be removed:

```
newdiv.className = 'added';
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rjXXa/2/

Comment: Would you mind explaining the numerous problems in logic and errors he had in the code...? Simply posting a working solution won't do any any help for the OP or future readers (in terms of learning) ..

Comment: I get the logic you did. The one question I have though, how can I return the "Add more" link if i remove a dropdown menu after it hit 5? I tried if (counter != 5)  {         document.getElementById("add_more_text").appendChild(newdiv);
        }

Comment: perfect! thats what i was after!

Comment: How can I remove the first 'x' but have it show up for the others?

Answer (score 2):

in your onClick property

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="removeInput('template', 'add_more');">x</a>
```

you are passing `template` and `add_more`

And in the handler function

```
function removeInput(divName, template){
```

the parameters are in a different order, so `divName` will contain `'template'` and `template` will contain `'add_more'`. Even if you fix this,

```
document.getElementById(template).removeChild(divName); // will throw error
```

because the `div#add_more` is not a child of `div#template`.

For fixing this, you need to pass a reference to the clicked element, like the following

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="removeInput(this);">x</a>
```

and in your function

```
function removeInput(anchor){ 
 var clone = anchor.parentNode; // div containing the anchor
 if(clone.id!='template'){ // make sure we're not removing the original template 
  clone.parentNode.removeChild(clone);
  counter--;
 }
}
```

as in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/rjXXa/3/)

**Update**

It's better to remove the `add more` option from display using css and make it visible later  than removing/appending it in DOM, as follows

change the following in `addInput()` function

```
if (counter > 4)  {
    document.getElementById("add_more_text").style.display='none';
}
```

and in `removeInput()` function add

```
 if (counter < 5)  {
    document.getElementById("add_more_text").style.display='block';
 }
```

as in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/rjXXa/6/)

Comment: @dfsq thank you, i added it since there was no reply from you and i've lots of free time since it's weekend :D

Comment: Thank you for your help! That was really informative